# Import, DirectAgglomerate, DendogramPlot- why must I execute every command seperately?

Tags: plotting, import, cluster-analysis

I have a big distance matrix in a file and I want to do clustering and plot dendgoram. I've tried:

```
Needs["HierarchicalClustering`"]      
      DendrogramPlot[
        DirectAgglomerate[
         Import["C:\\here_path\\distance_matrix.txt"]
        ]
      ]
```

But unfortunatelly it returns:

```
DendrogramPlot[DirectAgglomerate["{
  {0.0, 0.051, 0.072243, 2.397, 0.11146, 1.23, 1,21, 0.451, \
0.0901, 1.466, 0.24518, 0.5529},
   next rows of matrix.. }"]]
```

And I have to copy matrix to DirectAgglomerate and then copy output to DedogramPlot, because I can even combine those two commands.

Edit:

Sample of matrix [here at pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Nafkcwzi)

Comment: What is the data format in your text file? It seems that `Import` is returning a string, rather than an expression. Try wrapping your `Import` call in `ToExpression`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the same output (only without splitting "\")

Comment: Data you posted is not a _matrix_: the first row has 13 elements and the rest 12. Also check to make sure the matrix is symmetric.

Comment: It is a symmetric matrix. Also when I copy it DirectAgglomerate it's ok, but I  cannot use DirectAgglomerate and DendgramPlot at the same time.

Comment: Please post a file that can actually be imported, not one with omissions like "..." and typos like "1,21" instead of "1.21".

Answer (score 4):

This is a comment with code. There is nothing wrong with daisy-chaining those commands. See e.g.

```
Needs["HierarchicalClustering`"]
DendrogramPlot@DirectAgglomerate@RandomReal[1, {12, 12}]
```

Your problem is in the format in which you saved the data. `Import` returns a string from your text file; `DirectAgglomerate` doesn't know how to handle it, and returns unevalulated. You need to convert your string into an expression, using e.g. `ToExpression`.

For instance, let's generate a file similar to yours, but containing random data:

```
Put[RandomReal[1, {12, 12}], "temp.txt"]
```

Then let's import it, convert it to an expression, and apply the other operations:

```
DendrogramPlot@DirectAgglomerate@ToExpression@Import["temp.txt"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1; however, the documentation for [`DirectAgglomerate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/HierarchicalClustering/ref/DirectAgglomerate.html) states that the "distance matrix m can be any symmetric matrix." The fact that it accepted a non-symmetric matrix without a warning or error message concerning this, seems like a shortfall.

Comment: @BobHanlon That's a good point. I hadn't really given thought to the actual functionality here. Indeed, `DirectAgglomerate` only complains about ties when fed a random matrix, not about the structure of the matrix itself, and still produces a result.